# to display one view in another view by clicking button

Tags: iphone

hi guys i am new to iphone apps development please help me to show another view from one view using buttons

Comment: Did you google? or Atleast did you go through UIViewController class reference? Use "- (void)presentModalViewController:(UIViewController *)modalViewController  animated:(BOOL)animated" in "On button click" action handler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats a very vague question... here is a start - you can look up some of the syntax and research a bit:

this in viewDidLoad:

```
UIButton *button  = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[button setTitle:@"Click" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(showView) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.view addSubview:button];
[button release];
```

then this method

```
- (void)showView {
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRect(0,0,320,460)];
    [self.view addSubview:view];
    [view release];
}
```

if you want to push a view controller then you need to look up navigation controllers and the method `pushViewController:animated:`

Answer (score 0):

This is the common code u can use to go on next view or go on back, Just change button name which u want to press and the view name on which u want to go. For example on back button press u want to go on library view then write this code -

```
-(IBAction)backButtonPressed:(id) sender 
{ 
     libraryView *libraryview=[[libraryView alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];   
     libraryview.modalTransitionStyle=UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical; 
     [self presentModalViewController:libraryview animated:YES]; 
     [libraryview release]; 
}
```

Let me know whether ur problem is solved or not.